# MonoRepo: Issue with `npm link` and `regenerator-runtime`: Local Package Linking Causes Errors in Different Scenarios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, npm-link, regenerator-runtime

I'm encountering a peculiar issue when trying to link a local sub-project package (`x`) in the frontend project of a monorepo using `npm link`. The problem manifests differently depending on the order of commands I execute. First, I cloned and ran `npm install` in both repositories. Second, I run `yarn build` and `npm link` in the x project. Then, here's what I'm doing next in the frontend project:

**Scenario 1:**

1. I run `npm link @monorepoName/x`.
2. Then, I run `npm install regenerator-runtime@latest`.
3. Finally, I execute `npm run dev:hot`.

After these steps, the link to my local `x` project gets removed, and my frontend project seems to revert to using the `x` version from the npm repository.

**Scenario 2:**

1. First, I run `npm install regenerator-runtime@latest`.
2. Then, I execute `npm link @monorepoName/x`.
3. Lastly, I run `npm run dev:hot`.

In this scenario, when I open the project URL in the browser, I get an error: `'Uncaught ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined'`.

I don't know why the order of these commands impacts the behavior in such a way. I'm seeking insights into what might be causing these issues and how to resolve them.

Any suggestions on what might be causing these issues or how to properly link a local package while managing dependencies like `regenerator-runtime` would be greatly appreciated.

Let me know in the comments if you need more information.